# lapply changes data undesirably

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I am looking to apply an UDF to an entire dataframe via lapply. However, the act of doing so also coerces data in a way almost as if R wanted to dummy code the columns.

dummy data

```
df = data.frame(customer_id = c("c000000067", "c000678746")
                ,email = c("hello@gmail.com", "NULL")
                )
```

apply function

```
df[] = lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x=='NULL', NA, x)); View(df)
```

As one can see, both customer_id and email have had their data changed. I have in the past used lapply on selected columns with success

```
df[ , c('date_1', 'date_2')] = data.frame(lapply(df[ , c('date_1', 'date_2')] , FUN = function(x) as.Date(x, "%d/%m/%Y")))
```

However, applying over a whole dataframe seems to be failing. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Those are `factor` columns. Check the `str(df)`  You may need to convert to `character` class.  `lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x=='NULL', NA, as.character(x)))` or use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the `data.frame` call

Comment: Worked. As simple as that. I will bear in mind the importance of class when using apply in future. Thank you @akrun

Comment: @akrun Is there a way around 
~~~
as.character(x)
~~~
because after the use of this the entire dataframe's class becomes character.

Comment: Create the dataset with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`while reading the data with `read.csv/read.table` etc.  Regarding the edited comment, you showed a dataset with all columns as `factor`s.  Not sure about the actual dataset problem you have

Comment: It does work but I subsequently found as my csv has 'NULL' values, they render R's import (even with stringsAsFactors used) to set all columns with 'NULL' as character. Nonetheless, good to know your method, @akrun

Comment: @akrun My latest solution is to use na.strings=c("","NULL") instead of using the apply method. Still, apply is indispensable. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that is the best approach with `na.strings`